# Jquery - Expand image height and width 20% on hover

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-animate

Evening all - Whats the best way to access an image's height and width dynamically .
I want to add 20% to an images width and height and animate when the surrounding div is hovered, I guess I need to use 'this', but not sure how to access the image.

Any help greatfully received.

Cheers Paul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this, using [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) with function arguments:

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    $(this).height(function(i, h) { return h * 1.2; })
           .width(function(i, w) { return w * 1.2; });
}, function() {
    $(this).height(function(i, h) { return h / 1.2; })
           .width(function(i, w) { return w / 1.2; });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ebehQ/), if you wanted a smooth animation you could store the initial height/width and [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), like this:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'size', { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height*1.2, 
                             width: $.data(this,'size').width*1.2 });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height, 
                             width: $.data(this,'size').width });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qKXSg/), be sure to run either of these options in `$(window).load()`, and **not** `$(document).ready()`, since the dimensions may not be loaded yet.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods of jQuery:

```
$(".divs").mouseover(function() {

    var $div = $(this);
    var $item = $div.find("img");

    var width = $item.width();
    var height = $item.height();

    width = width * 1.2;
    height = height * 1.2;

    $item.width(width);
    $item.height(width);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divId").mouseover(function() {
    var o = $("#imgid");
    o.width(o.width()*1.2).height(o.height()*1.2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using animate, which should provide a smoother transition:

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({
        'height': $this.height() * 1.2,
        'width' : $this.width() * 1.2
    });
},function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.animate({
        'height': $this.height() / 1.2,
        'width' : $this.width() / 1.2
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't work quite as expected, since if you hover in/out before the animation finished, the new `.height()` and `.width()` values won't be their destination values, meaning it'll go back to some other size :) Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JqDMR/ the only change I made was that `$this` isn't defined in your code :)