# jQuery: How to add transition on hover, div's BORDER-RADIUS & MARGIN?

Tags: jquery, html, transition, jquery-hover

Language: **Javascript** / **jQuery** / **PHP**

What I am trying to accomplish, is similar to the hover effect that you see on this page's bubbles:
**https://www.vizify.com/rand-fishkin**

I have accomplished a similar effect using **CSS3**, but the transition was not as smooth as the one on that page, so I opted with using Javascript instead.

What I'm doing here is **I grow the width & height of the div bubble by 10% when hovered**.

But I do not know how to adjust the **border-radius** and **margin** by percentage?

```js
$(".colored-bg").each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'size', { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height*1.1, 
                         width: $.data(this,'size').width*1.1,
                         margin: '-13.5px auto' });
}, function() {
$(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height, 
                         width: $.data(this,'size').width,
                         margin: '-13.5px auto' });
});
```

**Upon hover :**

- I want to adjust the border-radius so that the bubble remains round
  even when hovered (1/2 number of pixels from the height/width of the hovered div size)
- I want to change the margin to 1/8 negative pixels (of the hovered div size) - dynamically - when hovered so that the div remains centered vertically (so that when it grows, it does not
  simply expand downwards).

Enough yapping, **[here is a demo](http://likebam.com/test/test.php)** reflecting what I've done so far.

Currently, I am using a fixed border-radius of 300px (larger than the div itself) to keep the div rounded even when hovered, and I am changing the margin in a static way (not based on percentage).

Since I am adding the grow transition based by **percentage**, I cannot do a static border-radius or static margins for the hovered div.

My question is, **how do I specify border-radius & margins by percentage?**

If this is how you expand the width by 10%: `width: $.data(this,'size').width*1.1`
How do you set the margin by 1/8 of the current height?

I have stumbled upon this post that kind of is doing what I want: [**https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630768/1399030**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630768/1399030) (dividing & outputting based on percentage)

Thanks so much, all assistance is really appreciated!

Comment: Working by percentage of the current value isn't going to work - not for height, width, border-radius or anything else. See the `.stop()` command? That means the start point of each animation is not necessarily the intended end point of the previous animation. You need to store the initial values, eg with `.data()`, and work from those values in all cases, ie if lower limit is x then upper limit is x*1.1.

Comment: Currently, this is storing the width & the height (LINE #2), but is there a way to store the div's margin & border radius? jQuery has `$(this).height()` but what could one use for margins & border-radius? Thank you for the response! I am not sure how to go about this... I have found 2 links that kind of are asking *almost* the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630768/1399030 || http://stackoverflow.com/q/590602/1399030

Comment: Doh! I beg your pardon - I misread the code. You are already doing what I suggest. I just woke up and haven't had any coffee yet.

Comment: ^LOL perfectly understandable! I am trying other things, how to spew out a margin that is relative to the height `margin: $.data(this,'size').height*1.2` <-- This currently just changes margin to 20% bigger, which doesn't make any sense but what I'm trying to get is to make the margin -1/8 pixels of the div height: `margin: X auto`. I have no idea how to make **X** dynamic via jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love,

Try this:

```
$(".bubble").on('scale', function(e, s) {
    var data = $.data(this, 'size'),
        w = data.width,
        h = data.height;
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: w * s,
        height: h * s,
        marginLeft: data.marginLeft - w * (s-1) / 2,
        marginTop: data.marginTop - h * (s-1) / 2
    });
}).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.data(this, 'size', {
        width: $this.width(),
        height: $this.height(),
        marginLeft: parseInt($this.css('margin-left')),
        marginTop: parseInt($this.css('margin-top'))
    });
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).trigger('scale', [1.1]);
}, function() {
    $(this).trigger('scale', [1.0])
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gTz/)**

### NOTES

- By providing an excessive border-radius in the style sheet (eg. equal to width), circularity is guaranteed(?) without needing to scale it. I think this will work in all browsers but needs testing.
- To avoid repetition of code, I implemented the scaling algorithm as a handler of the custom event 'scale'.
- Margin scaling keeps bubble centred on its original centre.
- You will see in the demo that the bubble is wrapped in a static container that reserves space into which the bubble can expand. This will prevent the whole page needing to reflow as the bubble grows/shrinks. Other approaches are available, eg absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be using this! :) Thanks for the response & the help.